# fetching a plain/text with redux-api-middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-api-middleware

Can I fetch a txt file with `redux-api-middleware`? If yes, how? According to the [doc](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware#lifecycle) the body is set to `undefined` if not application/JSON compliant, but what I will get is a simple text/plain

Answer (score 1):

Basically what I did was altering `fetch` action and doing my custom stuff with response data. Example:

```
fetch: async (...args) => {
    const response = await fetch(...args);

    if (response.ok && response.status === 200) {
      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      const type = response.headers.get('content-type');
      const filename = filenameExtractor(response.headers.get('content-disposition'));
      const { value } = await reader.read();

      fileSaver({ value, filename, type });
    }

    return response;
  },
```

This piece of code reads response contents and pushes them for download to the browser. `filenameExtractor` and `fileSaver` are custom functions. This way response is not altered.

Using such approach you can further modify response and create json yourself for data to be able to be saved in redux like:

```
const response = await fetch(...args);

return new Response(
    JSON.stringify({ data: response.body })
);
```